# window.open makes page scroll up

Tags: javascript

i'm using a windows.open popup and when i click it the page automatically goes up, how do i prevent this? i tried 'top:auto' it doesnt work here is my code

> ```
>  function openPopup() {
>
>         var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
>         var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=200,top=100');
>         var doc = myWindow.document;
>         doc.open();
>         doc.write(divText);
>         doc.close();
>     }
> ```

```
           <a href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Read More</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain scroll position in Javascript window.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372907/maintain-scroll-position-in-javascript-window-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is executing your onClick handler, then continuing with the default behavior -- clicking the link, which causes the browser to scroll to the `#` anchor. (The location bar will also get a # at the end to reflect this.) You want your onClick handler to suppress the click event, so have it `return false`:

```
       <a href="#" onclick="openPopup(); return false">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `window.open`, it's the `href="#"`.

I always use `href="javascript:void(null);"` for links that will be powered by an `onclick`, but you can just use `javascript:;` or add `return false;` at the end of the `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openPopUp()".`