# jQuery prevent parent scroll to top when using window.open();

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks on the button to open the pop up the parent window scrolls to the top.  Is there any way I can prevent this?

```
$("#diary").on( "click", ".add_job_open", function (){
    var week_start = $(this).siblings('.week_start').val();
    user_id = $('.user').text();
    window.open('add_weekly_job.php?week_start='+week_start, '_blank',
    'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=600,width=500,left=200, top=300');
  });
```

The parent window is called diary_weekly.php

I have found a similar question but the user is using an a anchor rather than a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain scroll position in Javascript window.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372907/maintain-scroll-position-in-javascript-window-open)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I have seen that question and they are using an a tag rather than a button as in my code

Comment: Wither using a button (eg submit button) or a link, use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the callback to stop the default action of the element. Or change the button to a non-submit button: `<input type="button">`

Comment: I didn't realize you were using an HTML `button`. If you're still having issues please post your HTML code, preferably a Stack Snippet or JSFiddle that recreates the problem.

Comment: @PatrickEvans perfect thanks!  Please add an as answer and I will accept it